# How to make ExpressionEngine tag Non-case Sensetive

Tags: ee2, solspace, tags

I am using [Solspace ExpressionEngine Tag](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/tag), its working very well, but I need to fix one thing:-

I have tagged a story "Costa Rica" (the country). The module automatically converts it to "costa rica". 
Since the module is case sensitive, I now have two (or perhaps 3 or 4) sets of tags: "costa rica", "Costa Rica", and possibly "Costa rica". 
So if I search for "costa rica"  I only get a couple of stories; if I search for "Costa Rica" I get a few more. 
Like this there must be many more. Is it possible to make the module NOT case-sensitive? I cannot see a setting for that.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is have Tag convert to lowercase.  There is a setting for that under preferences.